# Why compilation error is giving in this java code?

Tags: java

I was trying to compile the code and it shows a compilation error. Can anyone help me out to understand what is wrong in the code? I guess there should be a default constructor inside Mammal class but why?

```
class Mammal {
 public Mammal(int age) {
 System.out.print("Mammal");
 }
 }
 public class Platypus extends Mammal {
 public Platypus() {

 System.out.print("Platypus");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Mammal(7);   //Compilation Error
 }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Mammal` class, there's no default constructor. Either add a default Constructor or Call `super(age);` from `Platypus` constructor

```
 class Mammal {
 public Mammal(){}
 public Mammal(int age) {
 System.out.print("Mammal");
 }
 }
 public class Platypus extends Mammal {
 public Platypus() {

 System.out.print("Platypus");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Mammal(7);   //Compilation Error
 }
}
```

## OR

```
class Mammal {
 public Mammal(int age) {
 System.out.print("Mammal");
 }
 }
 public class Platypus extends Mammal {
 public Platypus() {
     super(0);
 System.out.print("Platypus");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Mammal(7);   //Compilation Error
 }
}
```